# UIScrollView crashes if setContentOffset is called with animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

My application creates instances of a custom subclass of UIView and adds those instances placed horizontally adjacent to each other. When a new instance of my UIView class is created, I can add it to the UIScrollView and reset the contentsize. I then call 
`[UIScrollView setContentOffset:(some point) animated:NO]`. 
This works just fine.
The issue is when I call the above mentioned method with animation, i.e. 
`[UIScrollView setContentOffset:(some point) animated:YES]`
, the application crashes. 
The call stack looks like this:

```
> #0    0x3145b870 in ___forwarding___ ()
> #1    0x313b6650 in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
> #2    0x317d84a2 in -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] ()
> #3    0x317d84a2 in -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] ()
> #4    0x317d7f0e in -[UIAnimator(Static) _advance:withTimestamp:] ()
> #5    0x317d7e00 in -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] ()
> #6    0x3531d86e in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
> #7    0x3531d7c4 in CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*,
> unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) ()
> #8    0x33a56000 in IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc ()
> #9    0x36e3c60c in IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage ()
> #10   0x31422f12 in __CFMachPortPerform ()
> #11   0x3142d522 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
> #12   0x3142d4c4 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
> #13   0x3142c312 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
> #14   0x313af4a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
> #15   0x313af36c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
> #16   0x32888438 in GSEventRunModal ()
> #17   0x316b4cd4 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

When I enable Zombies, the application output produces:

```
*** -[__NSArrayM removeObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x113dbb10
```

Additional Info: UIScrollView's delegate is never set. I am using ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my issue. 
I was calling the method that called setContentOffset from a background thread.

```
BackgroundThread --> My random processing method --> Setup new UIView and add it to UIScrollView --> Call setContentOffset with animations
```

The above flow causes the crash. When I called the same processing method from the main thread, it worked just fine.

Apparently iOS does not like animations called from a background thread.

Comment: If there is one rule on iOS and OSX, its never ever ever manipulate the UI on any thread but the main thread. Rule #1. Its not that it does not like it, its that its forbidden and apple documents this is more than one place.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the fact that I was calling this method from a background thread. Just thought I'd post my answer in case someone was in the same frustrating position.

Comment: Don't forget to select it as the answer when SO lets you! So people know the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

One of the views in the scrollView is getting released. Probably you "jump" over it when you turn animation off - when its on, the system tries to get a series of "snapshots" of the changes, and when it tries to access the one view boom down you go. So you can enable Zombies and find out exactly what type of object is getting the message, and in the debugger you can probably "po" that object.

Another way to do it would be to write our own test animation, move the contentOffset say 20 pixels at a time in a loop with no animation, and watch to see when it crashes (it surely will)!

Comment: I tried a manual loop and that didn't seem to cause any problems albeit the screen kinda just jumped to the offset without any animation. My loop was the equivalent of calling setContentOffset with no animation.